# Limiting Formtastic collection in a many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, formtastic

I have successfully integrated formtastic to my rails project and used it to do multi value select in a many-to-many relation.

The issue is that I can't seem to find how to limit the choices to those that are relevant.

Given the following:

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :poolings, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :commercials, :through => :poolings
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :poolings
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :commercials
 belongs_to :client
end
```

the relation many-to-many model

```
class Pooling < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :pool
 belongs_to :commercial
end
```

and the commercial model

```
class Commercial < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :client
 has_many :poolings, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :pool, :through => :poolings
end
```

The following code works to create the multiple select form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @pool do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs %>
  <%= f.inputs :commercials %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

The key being the assumption of formtastic that the :commercials translate into the many-to-many select form.

Now reading the documentation, I could not understand what to add to the line

```
<%= f.inputs :commercials %>
```

So that when I use it in a form to edit a "pool" where the "client_id = 1", it will show me only the "commercials" with the "client_id =1.

Using the following with collection select gives me the intended result:

```
<%= f.collection_select :commercials, Commercial.where(:client_id => @pool.client), :id, :name %>
```

What is the equivalent in formtastic?

And BTW, being new to RoR I find it very confusing that various component and gems all seems to do things slightly differently. The joy of open source!

Answer (score 0):

There is a "collection" parameter for selects, checkboxes and radios (see [Usage](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#usage)).

For your specific problem, the solution could look something like this:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @pool do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :commercials, :collection => Commercial.where(:client_id => @pool.client) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```